# oracle sdo buffer and relate

Tags: oracle, plsql, geometry, oracle-spatial

Use the exact layer and one object

Create buffer point - 30 centimeter

```
WITH BUFF AS (select /*+ ALL_ROWS */
              T.Id,
              m.sdo_diminfo,
              mdsys.sdo_geom.sdo_buffer(T.gdo_geometry, m.sdo_diminfo, 0.15,'unit=meter') gdo_geometry
         from geo.TEST T, mdsys.SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE m
        where T.Id = 100
          and m.sdo_table_name = 'TEST' 
          and m.sdo_owner = 'GEO')
```

Search contains relate

```
SELECT BUFF.Id
   ,(select mdsys.sdo_geom.relate(BUFF.gdo_geometry, BUFF.sdo_diminfo, 'mask=contains', C.gdo_geometry, BUFF.sdo_diminfo) 
       from geo.TEST C 
      where C.Id = BUFF.Id) R01
  FROM BUFF
```

why returns FALSE?

Comment: I don't know. Modified your query for my table and it returns MASK=CONTAINS for all geometries in my table.

Comment: What values do you have in DIMINFO?